# Is there such thing as 'Unicode collation'?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, internationalization

Or if it does not, then what is actually a Sql Server `collation`? Maybe my understanding of collation (as a concept) is wrong.

I do not wish to specify my collation to greek or icelandic or even western-european. I wish to be able to use any language that is supported in Unicode.

(I'm using MSSQL 2005)

UPDATE: Ok, I'm rephrasing the question: Is there a generic, culture-independent collation that can be used for texts of any culture? I know it will not contain culture-specific rules like 'ty' in Hungarian or ß=ss in German, but will provide consistent, mostly acceptable results.

Is there any collation that is *not* culture-specific?

Comment: Use `nvarchar` etc instead of `varchar` then. The collation still has a role in determining comparison (and hence sorting) rules but doesn't affect the range of characters that can be stored in this case.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31861/19091 gives a great explanation of what a collation is/does in the context of SQL server.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, there's always a binary collation like Latin1_General_BIN2. It stores the code points in numerical order, which can be pretty arbitrary. It's not culture-specific though (despite the name).

It sounds like there isn't any intelligent way to sort data from multiple languages/cultures together so instead of a half-baked solution, all you can do is sort by the binary values.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good article to know what is collation, short and sweet: [SQL Server and Collation](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3302341/SQL-Server-and-Collation.htm).

Collation is something which will allow you to compare and sort the data. As far as I can remember there is nothing like Unicode collation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a default Unicode collation, the
"Default Unicode Collation Element Table (DUCET)",
described in the Unicode Collation Algorithm Technical Standard document
http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/.

But one calls it the default Unicode collation rather than
the Unicode collation because of course there is more than
one -- for example the unicode.org chart for Hungarian
http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/28/collation/hu.html
describes how Hungarian collation for Unicode
characters differs from the DUCET.

Since this question was asked the
SQL Server collations have become more Unicode-aware
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017. Meanwhile some open-source DBMSs have gained the ability to support DUCET and other Unicode collations, by incorporating the ICU (International Components for Unicode) library.